# Merge intervals in one for-loop

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, merge, array-merge

This might be a strange question but I'm trying to merge interval times and am just bothered that there's one line outside of the for-loop -- I really want to merge that line (haha.) into the for-loop and have everything happen at once.

Problem: Say for example you're given the Intervals (1, 5), (3, 7), (4, 6), (6, 8), (10, 12), (12, 15) the program should return (1,8),(10,15) as these merge all overlapping intervals.

My approach is that I have a current value with the values of the first pair, I then run a for-loop from 1 to the end and check if the Pair that I'm on merges with my current or not. If it does merge I update the values in my current pair and if it doesn't merge then I add current to my result list and then update its values to whatever node I'm currently on.

Feel free to change up the code however necessary to make it all work in one for-loop.
If you see any other errors with the code, please let me know. Thank you!

```
class Pair{
    public int first;
    public int second;
    
    public Pair(int x, int y){
      this.first = x;
      this.second = y; 
    }
}

class MergeIntervals{
  static ArrayList<Pair> mergeIntervals(ArrayList<Pair> v) {
  ArrayList<Pair> result = new ArrayList<Pair>();
 
  //check for size & null
  if(v == null || v.size() == 0) {
    return null;
  } 
  if(v.size() == 0) {
    result.add(v.get(0));
    return result;
  }

  Pair current = new Pair(v.get(0).first, v.get(0).second);

  for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {

    //want to merge
    if(v.get(i).first < current.second) {
      if(v.get(i).second > current.second) {
        current.second = v.get(i).second;
      }
    }
    else {
      result.add(new Pair(current.first, current.second));
      current.first = v.get(i).first;
      current.second = v.get(i).second;
    }
  }
  //loop broke before was able to merge
  result.add(new Pair(current.first, current.second));

  return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Right after the want to merge comment it should probably be <= and not <.

Comment: Also, if size == 1 you add element 0 and not if size == 0, which could be replaced by v.isEmpty() in the if before it.

Comment: And finally you can just add current at the end as it doesn't get modified any more. If you want it in the loop, which I wouldn't recommend, just add if(i == v.size() - 1) before it and put it at the end of the loop, but then you can as well break after adding the last element in the if and remove i < v.size() from the for. Otherwise you basically check the same thing twice.

Comment: When `(v.get(i).first < current.second)` you should extend both ends: `current.first = Math.min(current.first, v.get(i).first); current.second = Math.max(current.second, v.get(i).second);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize possible changes/enhancements to the existing code:

- in class `Pair` provide a copy constructor and override `toString()` for convenience
- enhance verification of the input data in `merge` method
- sort the input data to guarantee order of the intervals
- use `Pair` copy constructor in the `merge` method

```java
class Pair{
    public int first;
    public int second;
    
    public Pair(int x, int y){
        this.first = x;
        this.second = y; 
    }
    
    public Pair(Pair p) {
        this(p.first, p.second);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")";
    }
}

class MergeIntervals{
    public static List<Pair> merge(List<Pair> v) {
        if (null == v) {
            return null;
        }
        // early return an empty list or containing a single pair
        if (v.size() < 1) {
            return v;
        }
        List<Pair> result = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Collections.sort(v, (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.first, b.first));
        
        Pair current = new Pair(v.get(0));
        
        for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
            Pair p = v.get(i);
            if (p.first <= current.second) {
                current.second = Math.max(p.second, current.second);
            } else {
                result.add(current);
                current = new Pair(p);
            }
        }
        result.add(current);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
List<Pair> data = Arrays.asList(
    new Pair(3, 7),
    new Pair(1, 5),
    new Pair(6, 8),
    new Pair(4, 6),
    new Pair(10, 12),
    new Pair(12, 15)
);

System.out.println(MergeIntervals.merge(data));
```

Output:

```
[(1, 8), (10, 15)]
```